# Filter repeated keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please I'm new to this. I have searched, what I saw left me confused.

How can I reduce duplicated items in an array and add the values of the duplicated key to the unique one like below.

I want to have it like `arrayA`

```
let arrayA = [
  { name: "temperature", data: {"2000-09-26": 82} },
  { name: "temperature", data: {"1997-03-08": 71} },
  { name: "current", data: {"1993-08-11": 79} },
  { name: "frequency", data: {"2004-01-17": 16} },
  { name: "current", data: {"1997-02-14": 65} }
]

let arrayB = [
  { name: "temperature", data: {"2000-09-26": 82, "1997-03-08": 71} },
  { name: "current", data: {"1993-08-11": 79, "1997-02-14": 65} },
  { name: "frequency", data: {"2004-01-17": 16} }
]
```

Comment: would you like to go from a to b or from b to a? btw, what have you tried?

Comment: I want to go from a to b

Comment: What I tried was using variable as the key

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#reduce` and `Object.values()`. Create a hash of `name` and add the `data` value for a given `name`. Then get the values from the object using `Object.values()`.

```js
let arrayA = [ { name: "temperature", data: {"2000-09-26": 82} }, { name: "temperature", data: {"1997-03-08": 71} }, { name: "current", data: {"1993-08-11": 79} }, { name: "frequency", data: {"2004-01-17": 16} }, { name: "current", data: {"1997-02-14":
65} } ],
    result = Object.values(arrayA.reduce((r,{name, data}) => {
      r[name] = r[name] || {name, data: {}};
      Object.assign(r[name].data, data);
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
let arrayB = arrayA.reduce((acc, curr) => {

    const found = acc.find(i => i.name === curr.name)
    if (found) {
        // If this object is already there, merge their `data` property 
        Object.assign(found.data, curr.data)
    } else {
        // Otherwise add to the accumulator (`acc`)
        acc.push(curr)    
    }

    return acc
}, [])
```

Reference to the reduce function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrayA = [ { name: "temperature", data: {"2000-09-26": 82} }, { name: "temperature", data: {"1997-03-08": 71} }, { name: "current", data: {"1993-08-11": 79} }, { name: "frequency", data: {"2004-01-17": 16} }, { name: "current", data: {"1997-02-14": 65} } ]
var arrayB=_.map(_.groupBy(arrayA, 'name'),function(list){
    
    return _.reduce(list,function(nObj,obj){
                    if(nObj.data && _.difference(_.keys(nObj.data),_.keys(obj.data))){
                         nObj.data=_.assign(nObj.data,obj.data)
                    }else{
                       nObj=obj
                    }
                  return nObj
               },{})
})
console.log(arrayB)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.5.1/lodash.js"></script>
```